# Does definable imply recursively enumerable?

Tags: number-theory, logic

Is there any subset of the natural numbers that is definable but not recursively enumerable?

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are subsets $S$ that are recursively enumerable, but not recursive, there must be definable sets that are not recursively enumerable: the complement of $S$ would meet this criterion.